# Web application access different between Domain Name and IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, redhat, subdomain, jrun

in our office, we have a web application running.
When we access the application by the domain name, http://server.domain.com/application/name
it will display the current version of application.

However, when we go by the IP address, `http://192.168.1.111/application/name`
it will display the old version of that application.
One thing is that we can access that application either by
http://server.domain.com/ (it will be redirected to the long URL automatically) or http://server.domain.com/application/name
when we are using domain name.

But only accessible via the exact URL when we use IP address. Why is it showing the old version and how can it be corrected? It is running JRun4, Apache on Red hat.
I've checked in httpd.conf a bit but could not find any.
Please advice what should be done to display the same (updated version)
when we access using domain name or IP address. Thank you.

Comment: what ip is reported by the command `host server.domain.com`?

Comment: I am only using windows. if host command is similar to nslookup, the IP I get is 192.168.1.111.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with your [name-based virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) (vhost) configuration. When accessing your web server using your domain name, the web server finds the vhost configured with that domain name. Accessing it by IP address, the web server uses the default (`_default_` in Apache) vhost.

Search your Apache configuration for `<VirtualHost ...>` blocks.

Comment: In my httpd.conf, 3 VirtualHost are associated to that IP address. The first VirtualHost entry is `another.domain.com`. When I tried `http://another.domain.com/application/name`, it displayed the same page like the `http://192.168.1.111/application/name`. Is there a way to change in httpd.conf so that domain and IP access display the same content?